# Why is my javascript not working. I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is my javascript not working. I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top'  error. I am trying to do improvements to HtmlDiff library for displaying an extra Html function. Javascript is not functioning with previous and next buttons in my output.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.diff {font-family:Courier; border:medium;}
        .diff_header {background-color:#e0e0e0}
        td.diff_header {text-align:right}
        .diff_next {background-color:#E6E6FA}
        .diff_add {background-color:#aaffaa}
        .diff_chg {background-color:#ffff77}
        .diff_sub {background-color:#ffaaaa}
    .navigation {position:fixed;top: 0;right: 0;background: #FFFFFF;padding:5px;border: 1px solid;}
    </style>


  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type = "text/javascript">

    function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
      time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
      verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
      element = $(selector);
      offset = element.offset();
      offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, time);
  }


    $(document).ready(function () {
      count = 0;
      var max_length = $(' .diff_add  ').length;

      $('#next').click(function (e) {
          if (count < max_length) {
              count++;
          } else {
              count = 1;
//              alert("reached start point");
          }
          e.preventDefault();
          scrollToElement(' .diff_add  :nth-child(' + count + ')', 1000, -150);
      });
        $('#prev').click(function (e) {
          if (count > 1) {
              count--;
          } else {
              count = max_length;
//              alert("reached start point");
          }
          e.preventDefault();
          scrollToElement(' .diff_add  :nth-child(' + count + ')', 1000, -150);
      })
  });</script>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="navigation"> <a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a>

    <br> <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>

</div>

    <table class="diff" id="difflib_chg_to0__top" 
           cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="groups" >
        <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup> <colgroup></colgroup>

        <tbody>

            <tr><td class="diff_next"><a href="#difflib_chg_to0__216">n</a></td><td class="diff_header" id="from0_5589">5589</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_sub">60&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td><td class="diff_next"><a href="#difflib_chg_to0__216">n</a></td><td class="diff_header" id="to0_2547">2547</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_add">&nbsp;|&nbsp;29|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="diff_next"></td><td class="diff_header" id="from0_5590">5590</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_sub">---&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td><td class="diff_next"></td><td class="diff_header" id="to0_2548">2548</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_add">---|---|---&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="diff_next"><a href="#difflib_chg_to0__216">n</a></td><td class="diff_header" id="from0_5589">5589</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_sub">60&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td><td class="diff_next"><a href="#difflib_chg_to0__216">n</a></td><td class="diff_header" id="to0_2547">2547</td><td nowrap="nowrap"><span class="diff_add">&nbsp;|&nbsp;29|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="diff" summary="Legends">
        <tr> <th colspan="2"> Legends </th> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <table border="" summary="Colors">
                      <tr><th> Colors </th> </tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_add">&nbsp;Added&nbsp;</td></tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_chg">Changed</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td class="diff_sub">Deleted</td> </tr>
                  </table></td>
             <td> <table border="" summary="Links">
                      <tr><th colspan="2"> Links </th> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(f)irst change</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(n)ext change</td> </tr>
                      <tr><td>(t)op</td> </tr>
                  </table></td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

My original data has more number of rows in the table.

Comment: Just from a glance, I would assume your `'.diff_chg :nth-child(' + count + ')'` selector is not matching any elements.  The element with the `diff_chg` class is a td, which does not appear to have any children other than a textNode.

Comment: I have changed it to .diff_add. Can you please tell me what changes that I have to make.

Comment: The same thing is true for `diff_add`.  It also doesn't have any children.  What exactly are you trying to select?  Take note that when you have a selector like `selector1 selector2`, the space between the selector parts denotes a parent child relation.  It's saying find elements matching selector2 that are children of selector1.  If you want it to be an AND conditional, you don't put the space in there.

Comment: max_length is giving the sum of number of diff_add present in code. How should I change my  '.diff_add:nth-child(' + count + ')' selector? so that each time diff_add of a particular count is selected.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for `$(.diff_add:eq(' + count + ')')`

Comment: yeah, exactly. Thank you.